# Trying to recreate a slide in element when you scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for some guidance on how I can recreated a this feature. what it does is when you scroll past a certain point something slides in on the right. You can see it action here. 
http://mashable.com/2011/08/19/hp-touchpad-lower-prices-canada/#comment-17611181

can anyone help me understand how that happens? The source code tells me nothing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There probably is a jQuery plugin that does what you need already, but since I don't one, here's the basic procedure:

1. Set scroll-event listener on the window: `$(window).scroll(function(){…});`
2. In that event listener function, check the `window.scrollY` property which is how many pixels the page is scrolled down
3. If that value is above/below a certain threshold, show/hide the sliding element respectively

You can also use `window.scrollY + window.innerHeight` to find lowest pixel position that's visible in the browser. And you can then compare that to the position of some element low on the page. For instance, if you want the sliding element to appear when the user scrolls to the bottom of the main content, check whether the content element's lower edge (i.e. top-offset + height) is less than scrollY+innerHeight. If it is, then the user has scrolled to or past the content element, and you can slide the element in.

The sliding element iself should be styled with `position:fixed` (which won't work in IE6, by the way, but [there are ways around that](http://www.google.com/search?q=position+fixed+ie6)) and anchored to the rigth/bottom of the window. The sliding animation should then animate the `right` position from negative the element's width to zero, to slide it in (the opposite applies when hiding it)

[Here's a simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c8YSk/1/) (no animation, just hide/show)